# Problems sending Monero using GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am having some issues with the latest version of the Monero GUI wallet (version 0.16.0.3).  I downloaded the Windows 64 bit installer version from this website - https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/.....It installs fine and I can see all my Monero in the wallet.....However when I try and send the Monero anywhere I get a message stating "Transaction being created" and then the program just shuts down and the coins have not been sent.  This has happened to me several times and I have tried logging into the wallet over the last 2 weeks and have had the same issue.....Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you using the GUI in conjunction with a hardware device (e.g. Ledger or Trezor)?

Comment: Yes I am using a trezor device with the GUI

Comment: Have you already updated the firmware to the latest version? Also, which `Wallet mode` are you using? You can check it on the `Settings` page.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the latest version of Monero (vs 0.16.0.3)...I have also recently updated the software on my trezor device via the offical website.

Comment: I am using the simple mode for the wallet.....Now I get a message that the transaction is being created but then an error message pops up stating; "Can't create transaction, unexpected error, call method failed".....Now what could that be?

Comment: Can you perhaps switch to `Advanced mode` and use a dedicated remote node? https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#remote-node | Let me know if you need specific instructions on how to switch to `Advanced` mode.

Comment: Thanks....I am not a techie so would appreciate some simple step by step instructions please

Comment: Try this: 1. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI and close the wallet. 2. Select `Advanced mode` as `Wallet mode`. 3. Reopen your wallet via the `Open a wallet from file` option. 4. Go to the `Settings` page. 5. Select `Remote node` 6. Fill in the node details consistent with the image here -> https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#remote-node 7. Press `Connect` 8. If it does not connect within 30 seconds, please try restarting the GUI.

Comment: Thanks.  But I do not know where my wallet is saved on my PC so cannot select the correct file when I select the "Open a wallet from File" option.

Comment: The wallet files should be stored in `Documents\Monero`

Comment: I don't have the answer but I'm experiencing the same problem. Can't send anything. "Can't create transaction: Unexpected error: Call method failed."

Comment: @Tenbad - Would you mind opening a new thread on r/monerosupport (Reddit)?